# How do I use "i" as an imaginary number in an equation in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, complex-numbers

Lets say I want to calculate Vout where Vout = (Vin/((I*w*R*C)+1));
where "i" should be defined as the sqrt(-1) . How do I do that in Objective-C?

Comment: Think of complex numbers as of vectors in complex plane.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980052/are-complex-numbers-already-defined-in-objective-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `#include <complex.h>` then use either `_Complex_I` or `I` macros (note the uppercase). The type of variables that contains complex values are denoted with the `_Complex` attribute, which can also be written simply `complex`.

```
double complex c1 = 1.0 + 2.0 * I; // 1+2i
double complex c2 = 2.0 + 3.0 * I; // 2+3i
double complex sum = c1 + c2;
double complex mul = c1 * c2;
```

You can then use the `creal` and `cimag` functions to get real and imaginary parts of a complex.

So in your case:

```
double Vin = 20; // in Volts
double w = 60; // frequency of your sinusoidal source (60Hz)
double R = 50; // 50 ohms
double C = 20e-6; // 20 µF
double complex invertZc = I*w*C; // Zc = 1/jwC, invertZc = jwC
double complex Vout = Vin / (1. + R*invertZc); // Vout = Vin * 1.0 / (1+Zr/Zc)
```

---

*Note that all this is provided by [the GNU C language (see here)](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Complex-Numbers.html), and are not specifically part of Objective-C itself but come from GNU C (Objective-C being a superset of C) and its extensions (which are supported by the GCC and LLVM compilers used by Xcode)*

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about the complex library. Thanks for sharing that nugget (voted)

Comment: Complex is part of standard C as of C99.

Comment: Cherry on the cake: this complex type is natively supported by / integrated in the Xcode debugger (both in LLDB and the Xcode interface). If you have a variable `complex double z = 1 + 2*I;` and put a breakpoint after this assignment and type `p z` in the LLDB console to print its value, it prints `(_Complex double) $0 = 1 + 2i` for example. And if you hover your mouse over the `z` variable in your code and wait for the tooltip to display its value, it displays "1 + 2i" as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Objective C does not have any built-in facility for handling complex numbers. You have to do the calculations yourself. Create a typedef of a struct imaginaryNumber that contains a real and imaginary part. Write functions that add and multiply those structures and return another one as a result. (To multiply 2 complex numbers (a1+b1i)•(a2+b2i) you treat the numbers as polynomials and use the FOIL method to calculate the result. The product of the 2 imaginary terms becomes a real number because i • i = -1.

Comment: Yes it does, as part of the GNU C superset. See http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Complex-Numbers.html