# Passing complex double value from ViewController to another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I need to pass complex double value from ViewController to another ViewController. XCODE prompted me with this error "Assigning to NSString from incompatible type 'complex number'"

ViewController.m

```
complex double  A=0+0*I;

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Calculate"]){
        [self ComputeABCD];
        ResultViewController *controller = (ResultViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.textContent = cascadedA;
    }
}
```

ResultViewController.m

```
@implementation ResultViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.result.text =  self.textContent;
}
```

ResultViewController.h

```
@interface ResultViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *result;
@property (nonatomic, assign) complex double textContent;
@property (nonatomic, assign) complex double textValue;

@end
```

Comment: Are you two in the same class? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415581/how-to-pass-complex-double-data-from-viewcontroller-to-another-viewcontroller

Comment: @rmaddy I have tried to declare both in same complex double but it's still prompted me error. Assigning to '_Complex double *' from incompatible type '_Complex double'

Comment: Notice the `*` in the error message. That makes a big difference.

Comment: How can I transfer the complex double from one view controller to another? can you provide me a solution please?.

Comment: Read the error message. It is clearly telling you the problem. You obviously have declared the `result` property incorrectly.

Comment: The result is a UILabel. How can I declare label to value ?

Comment: You've mentioned two errors: "Assigning to NSString from imcompatible type 'complex number'" and "Assigning to '_Complex double *' from incompatible type '_Complex double'". Obviously the 1st error is from the code you posted since you are trying to assign `A` to the `text` property of the label. Where is the 2nd error from?

Comment: @rmaddy I have declare complex double variable for the 1st viewcontroller and want to transfer the complex double value to 2nd viewcontroller and display it at label. Please see the amend question

Comment: Why are the `complex double` properties declared as pointers? They shouldn't be.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm using complex number and I need decimal too

Comment: But why are they pointers? They shouldn't be pointers. They are primitive types, not objects.

Comment: I'm really new to Objective-C and programming? I don't understand what u mean? can u tell me what is wrong? I have remove all the complex and leave with double now.

Comment: I said nothing about removing `complex`. I said to remove the pointer (the asterisk). `@property (nonatomic, assign) complex double *textValue;` should be `@property (nonatomic, assign) complex double textValue;`

Comment: okay, I have remove the *textValue as you mention but what should I do to allow me to display my complex double value to Label? I wanted to tried convert into String but there is no complex double convertion. What can i do

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980052/are-complex-numbers-already-defined-in-objective-c

Comment: Hmm.. Sorry, I don't need printf. I need to be able to display to another Viewcontroller and display at the UILabel

Comment: Ugh. I know you don't need `printf`. But `NSString stringWithFormat` works exactly like `printf`.

Comment: I remove the complex from the textContent. NSString *doubletostr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", self.textContent];
    self.result.text = doubletostr;

Comment: @rmaddy Thank for your patient guidance and let me tried and error without give me the direct solution

Comment: @rmaddy do u know is there any guide on duplicate image from UIImage to UIScrollView

Comment: That's a different question.

Comment: @rmaddy hope u can give some advice and take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241102/drag-and-drop-image-from-uiimageview-to-uiscrollview-duplicate-image